# Docker compose health check failing for "Setup Jenkins" github action

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, github-actions

I'm trying to setup Jenkins instance using github actions https://github.com/snow-actions/setup-jenkins/

**workflow file**:

```
name: wf1
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  jenkins-local-gha:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: snow-actions/setup-jenkins@v1.1.0
        with:
          jenkins_home: jenkins_home
      - run: wget $JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
      - run: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -webSocket help
      - run: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -webSocket build job-1 -f -v -p param_1=p1
```

But it's throwing error that the container is unhealthy.

**compose.yml:**

```
services:
  jenkins:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        tag: ${JENKINS_IMAGE_TAG}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
```

I don't see anything much in the logs.

```
.
.
#8 DONE 9.4s

#9 [jenkins] exporting to image
#9 exporting layers
#9 exporting layers 1.2s done
#9 writing image sha256:c03eb50e9d869819787ae9488632b33a48ddfdc0dab2b22fd94a7baa181923a0 done
#9 naming to docker.io/library/v100-jenkins done
#9 DONE 1.2s
 Network v100_default  Creating
 Network v100_default  Created
 Container v100-jenkins-1  Creating
 Container v100-jenkins-1  Created
 Container v100-jenkins-1  Starting
 Container v100-jenkins-1  Started
 Container v100-jenkins-1  Waiting
container v100-jenkins-1 is unhealthy
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```